# How to add interaction term in GLM in python

Tags: python, glm, interaction

I am able to run GLM with following syntax;

```
y_train = dt_glm['Eligible Revenue']
x_train = dt_glm[['Upfront Contra','Distribution Inventory Eurofit Net USD','Upfront Contra','6U','BNB']]
model_glm = sm.GLM(y_train , x_train, family=sm.families.Gamma())
print(model_glm.fit().summary())
```

but I want to add interaction term also which I am not able to.

I tried in following way but it threw syntax error

```
x_train = dt_glm[['Upfront Contra'*'Distribution Inventory Eurofit Net USD','Upfront Contra','6U','BNB']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ":" with the glm api. Below an example using the dataset from [help page](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/glm.html), with the interaction term between `COUTAX` and `UNEMPF` specified as  `COUTAX:UNEMPF`:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas

data = sm.datasets.scotland.load(as_pandas=True)
df = data.data

gamma_model = smf.glm(formula='YES ~ COUTAX + UNEMPF + COUTAX:UNEMPF + MOR',
data=df, family=sm.families.Gamma())

gamma_model.fit()
```